# Why did the Menorah not have rings and staves like the Aron and Mizbe'ach?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, menorah--in-temple

Both the Aron HaKodesh and the Mizbe'ach had rings and staves which were inserted into the rings, for carrying purposes. Why didn't the Menorah also have these rings and staves?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: IIRC the Aron could not be touched so it had to be carried this way. Why DID the mizbe'ach have rings?

Comment: "Both the Aron HaKodesh and the Mizbe'ach": actually, **if** I recall correctly, both _mizb'chos_ did, as well as the _shulchan_.

Comment: Yes, the *shulchan* did too.  It's odd that the *menorah* doesn't have some indirect way of carrying it, like the others.  I wonder if somebody carried it directly or if they made a box for it (not described) or what.

Comment: This question inspired me to [ask about the size of the *menorah*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89341/472).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that was was a technical issue; gravity.

The Menorah was 18 Tefachim high, if which the lower half was mainly a narrow stem.

Since the poles had to be low enough that when put on somebody's shoulder the bottom of the Menora would be above the ground, they would have had to be attached to the stem.

Trying to carry a top-heavy Menorah with 1 or 2 poles attached to the lower half of the Menora would mean it would have constantly been at risk of falling over (if you had the strength to lift it *right way up* in the first place).

Comment: Also the Menorah had lots of good hand holds, unlike the cubical Mizbeach and aron

Comment: the arch of titus picture has the הַמֹּֽוט the carring stick on the bottom

Comment: @user16730 - I think you're confusing the chains around their necks for the rods - see http://www.padfield.com/italy/Rome_1/images/arch-of-titus-5.JPG for a hi-res picture

Comment: @user16730 Keep in mind that not everyone sees the depiction on the Arch of Titus as accurate. There's no reason to believe it's more accurate than Jewish sources.

Comment: @era yes there is. It was made by people who saw it.