# How large was the menorah?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, menorah--in-temple

This [question asking why the *menorah* didn't have rings and staves for carrying](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89320/472) reminded me that, unlike with the other *mishkan* objects, we're not given any dimensions for the *menorah*.  I've always imagined it as large enough to stand on the ground and provide overhead light.  (That image is probably reinforced by the arch of Titus, but I'd be cautious about inferring too much from that.)  But was it?

According to Rashi on [Shemot 25:31](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9886#showrashi=true&v=31), the *menorah* was cast from a talent of gold weighing 64 pounds (citing Tan. Beha’alothecha 3).  The size question also came up in our torah study recently, where none of the *chumashim* on hand provided illumination.  An engineer who was present told us that that amount of gold would yield something closer to a table lamp than a floor lamp.  [This site](https://invest.usgoldbureau.com/gold-bar-sizes) says that a kilo (2.2 pounds) of gold is about the size of an iPhone 6.  30 of those doesn't seem enough to make a large, solid (not hollow) *menorah*.

I know that the group in Jerusalem who are building utensils for the third temple interpret it as a floor lamp, like what I imagined.  I don't know their sources.

How tall was the *menorah*?  Sources, please.

Comment: useful: https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=weight+of+a+kikar&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: The "[equivalent to sixty-four pounds of gold]" in the Rashi translation you linked is an insertion of the translator, and I'm not sure where it comes from. From googling around, I'm getting the sense that people believe that a holy *kikar* ("talent") was something like 100-150 pounds.

Comment: @IsaacMoses thanks.  At our torah study the number we were talking about was 75lb, from a different Rashi edition.  I don't know that doubling gets us up to floor-lamp levels (square-cube law and all that), but 150 pounds seems a lot more workable.

Comment: That same section of Shemot says it's made of "hammered work".  One of my hobbies is working precious metals. Gold can be beaten pretty thin, all the way down to foil for coatings. 150 pounds, or even 58 pounds, despite gold's density, can make a pretty big hollow, hammered object.

Comment: @Gary with enough structural integrity to stand?  The *menorah* is all gold, unlike the *aron* and *shulchan*.  (I've used gold leaf in art so know it can get pretty thin, but also know to hold my breath when placing it. :-) )

Comment: A 1 oz gold coin is pretty solid.  Even something 1/2 or 1/3 the thickness would be able to be self supporting to a pretty large size.  Give me some time, and I'll look up the statistics and see how large something can get - remember, it can be thin at the top for the cups and thicker at the base.  Even more than a thousand years before the menorah was made, goldsmithing was a very developed craft, all over the then-civilized world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Talmud says on [Menachot 28b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.28b.46-48?lang=bi):

> אמר שמואל משמיה דסבא
>
> גובהה של מנורה **שמנה עשר טפחים**
>
> הרגלים והפרח ג' טפחים וטפחיים חלק וטפח שבו גביע וכפתור ופרח וטפחיים חלק וטפח כפתור ושני קנים יוצאין ממנו אחד אילך ואחד אילך ונמשכין ועולין כנגד גובהה של מנורה וטפח חלק וטפח כפתור ושני קנים יוצאין ממנו אחד אילך ואחד אילך נמשכין ועולין כנגד גובהה של מנורה וטפח חלק וטפח כפתור ושני קנים יוצאין ממנו אחד אילך ואחד אילך ונמשכין ועולין כנגד גובהה של מנורה וטפחיים חלק נשתיירו שם ג' טפחים שבהן ג' גביעין וכפתור ופרח
>
> Samuel said in the name of an old scholar, The height of the candlestick was **eighteen
> handbreadths**: three handbreadths for the base and the flower upon it, two handbreadths plain,
> one handbreadth for cup, knop and flower, again two handbreadths plain, one handbreadth for a knop
> out of which two branches come forth, one on each side, extending and rising to the same height as
> the candlestick, then one handbreadth plain, one handbreadth for a knop out of which two branches
> come forth, one on each side, extending and rising to the same height as the candlestick, then again
> one handbreadth plain, and one handbreadth for a knop out of which two branches come forth, one
> on each side, extending and rising to the same height as the candlestick, and then two handbreadths
> plain; there now remained three handbreadths, in which space were three cups, a knop and a
> flower.

<sup>Translation from [Soncino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soncino_Press), via [halakhah.com PDF](https://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Menachoth.pdf).</sup>

Assuming the value in [this OU glossary](https://www.ou.org/judaism-101/glossary/tefach/) of 3.2 inches per *tefach*, that comes to about 58 inches tall.

Comment: Since the OP is happy quoting Rashi, she may like to know that Rashi quotes  Menachos 28b in his comments to 25 (35) on the words "...וְכַפְתֹּ֡ר תַּ֩חַת֩ שְׁ֨נֵי הַקָּנִ֜ים".